# ¿Como formatear a 0.x valores como .2, .12, .69 en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo un input number con un step de valor any, es posible colocar cualquier cantidad.

Limite que el valor no pasara de X numero, pero como es posible agregar valores decimales, ocurrio un problema a la hora de hacer el ingreso del valor.

El problema es que es posible agregar valores como *.54, .60, .09*, los cuales corresponderían a *"0.54, 0.60, 0.09"*. Entonces a la hora de guardar los registros habrán algunos con *0.100, 0.95, 0.776* y otros con *.949, .10, 0.5*.

¿Como puedo condicionar el campo para que transforme las cantidades sin el primer cero, en cantidades con cero?

Comment: seguin entiendo la pregunta quieres formatear los numeros, es decir un [toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: Por curiosidad, si es un  input number, ¿cómo es que al guardarlos algunos es como 0.100 y otros como .10? ¿Estás guardándolos como una cadena en lugar de como un número?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

llamando la función para que formatee el monto y luego usando la funcion call (para llamarla en contexto del input)

```js
function cambiarADecimal(el) {

    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(3);
}
const $miNumero = document.getElementById("miNumero");
const $miNumero1 = document.getElementById("miNumero1");
const $miNumero2 = document.getElementById("miNumero2");
cambiarADecimal.call($miNumero);
cambiarADecimal.call($miNumero1);
cambiarADecimal.call($miNumero2);
```

```html
<input type="number" value=".9" step="0.001" id="miNumero" />



<input type="number" value=".949" step="0.001" id="miNumero1" />


<input type="number" value=".10" step="0.001" id="miNumero2" />
```

Comment: Creo que tienes un error, porque pasas event a la funcion y luego usas es this?, o el onchange.value guarda el valor como si se tratara del this.value?

Comment: `function cambiarADecimal(element) {
   console.log(element.value)
   element.value = parseFloat(element.value).toFixed(2);
  }`

Comment: es decir, que no es necesario pasarle el this en el onchange no?, aja, ahora otra duda, como hago para que el valor NO sea redondeado, ni truncado?, o de por si esto NO redondea?, porque ahorita probe ingresando 0.649 y salio 0.65

Comment: de todas maneras voy a pasar el this en el onchange pero pudieces cambiar esto por addEventListener

Comment: Lo converti en una funcion y la pase al onchange usando this como parametro, qudando asi:

`function format(element) {
   console.log(element.value)
   element.value = parseFloat(element.value);
  }`

Comment: esto es una recomendacion trata de no usar la palabra format en el futuro te sonara que es una funcion reservada

Comment: Excelente gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Lo que podría hacer es evaluar el valor del **input** cada vez que cambie, y evaluarlo con una expresión regular, y si este inicia con un punto (.), concatenarle un cero a la izquierda:

```
var patt = new RegExp("^\..*");
var inputNumerico= document.getElementById("numCamponumerico");
inputNumerico.addEventListener("change", function(){
   if(patt.test(inputNumerico.value)){
      inputNumerico.value = "0"+inputNumerico.value;
   }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte :)

Answer (score 2):

Puesto que una etiqueta input siempre guarda su valor como texto, tendrías valores como un string. Así que puedes comprobar fácilmente si empiezan por un punto y añadir un cero delante:

```js
const button=document.getElementById('leer');
const valor=document.getElementById('valor');

button.addEventListener('click',function () {
  let v= valor.value;
  if (!+v) { return;}
  if (v.charAt(0) === '.') {
    valor.value = v = '0' + v;
  }
  
  //Hacer cosas con el valor
  console.log('Leído', v);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="valor" /><button id="leer" type="button">Leer</button>
```

Comment: Funciona igual de perfecto que la funcion de Jack, pero opto por el formato del mismo numero usando sus metodos