# Mostrar hasta cierta cantidad de decimales en Firefox y Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, chrome

tengo una pregunta, resulta que estoy modificando un input de un sistema, donde se hace ingreso de números decimales separados únicamente por "," resulta, que yo al ingresar, los valores en Chrome, me rellena con 0 los espacios vacíos, y en Firefox me deja los valores que uno coloca en el sistema. Cabe destacar que este sistema lo tengo montado en un local, les dejo acá abajo el código del input.

```
 <td class="valor cantidad"><input type="number" step="any" min="1"  value="'.$cantidad_prod.'" id="input_producto_cantidad_'.$row->id.'" class="'.$class.'" onchange="updateCantidad('.$row->id.');">                <cite>'.$row->unidad.'</cite></td>
```

La primera imagen es cómo se me ve en Firefox al ingresar 4,5

[image: Así se me ve en Firefox al ingresar 4,5]

La segunda imagen es cómo se me ve en Chrome al ingresar 4,5

[image: Así se me ve en Chrome al ingresar 4,5]

Necesito ayuda de cómo, modificar el código para que en ambos casos me quede o todo 4,500 ó 4,5 idealmente es que todo se vea como 4,5 y no adicione otros números. Porfavor ayuda! D:

Comment: ¿lo que intentas es que al cargar el dato automáticamente se trunque a dos decimales, o que sólo permita al usuario aumentar esos dos decimales?

Comment: Mmm, haz probado estableciendo los decimales en `step` es decir: `step="0.1"` de esa manera debería ponerse con un solo decimal.

Comment: mi idea es que el usuario ingrese los decimales que estime conveniente que el máximo son 4 digitos dsps de la coma, pero quiero que en la pantalla se vean únicamente los decimales que ingrese el usuario en ambos navegadores, por ejemplo: Si el usuario ingresa 4,56 en ambos navegadores debe verse 4,56 en Firefox pasa bien, pero en Chrome me rellena los otros 2 dígitos y queda así: 4,5600
Y si, he intentado poner `step="0,01"` pero aún así me arroja los dígitos faltante en Chrome. Lo ideal es dejarlo igual en ambos da lo mismo si es rellenando con ceros los dígitos restantes o no.

Comment: mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156193/28035) la solucion fue con un JavaScript

Comment: ¿pero quieres o no permitir que el usuario pueda escribir más de dos digitos?¿puede el usuario introducir un valor tal que 1,234567?

Comment: Lo ideal es que pongan hasta 3 dígitos, el usuario puede ingresar mas de 3 dígitos, pero el sistema lo acorta 3 después.

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entendí por los comentarios de tu publicación, lo que quieres es dejar que el usuario introduzca el valor que quiera, pero posteriormente redondearlo a dos decimales y que tanto en Firefox como en Chrome el comportamiento sea el mismo. El problema es obviamente de navegadores, como se comportan, así que para solucionar esto, además de acortar el propio valor a dos decimales, tienes que quitar los ceros restantes si es necesario para simular el comportamiento natural de Firefox en Chrome mediante la función `parseFloat`.

El `focusout` es necesario para así marcar el "fin" de la introducción de datos del usuario. Cuando quita el foco del input, formateamos el valor a nuestro antojo.

```js
function truncarValor(ele) {
  let value = Number(ele.value);
  if(isFloat(value)) {
    value = parseFloat(value.toFixed(2));
    
  }
  ele.value = value;
}

function isFloat(val) {
  return val%1 !== 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="myInput">El input: </label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="myInput" onfocusout="truncarValor(this);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: usé tu código, en mi sistema aplico modelo MVC, por tanto la primera parte de código, lo aplico en el controlador. Pero mi pregunta es, porqué `let`? Ya que me tira error en mi .php

Comment: Es código Javascript, claro que te tira error en PHP porque no es el mismo lenguaje... Por otro lado, el `let` es una de las maneras de declarar una variable en un lenguaje no tipado como JS, otra es `const` y la que existía anteriormente (pero no deberías usar más) es `var`